# Forward slash in Powershell

Tags: powershell

How do I check if a string contain a forward slash `"/"` in PowerShell?

The below:

```
  $sample = "abc/defg/hij"
  $sample -Contains "/"      
  $test = $sample -Replace "/", "__"
  $test
```

Gives this output:

```
False
abc__defg__hij
```

That makes no sense to me.

Comment: "-Contains" is used for checking for items in arrays and such. You want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"-Contains" is used for checking for items in arrays and such. You want

```
$sample -match "/"
```

Background at: [about_comparison_operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)